# How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

Just curious whether the process takes a while, and whether it scrapes through history to determine if it was once valid or not. Currently, I have 6 0-vote accepted answers and 20 1+-vote answers ([on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a355610%20isaccepted%3a1&tab=votes)), and that makes it > 5 and > 20% but not for long if voting goes up or down from here. ;-P

Update:

Special thanks to Grace Note for pointing out the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3a355610%20isaccepted%3a1&tab=votes) to follow. I upgraded this to a bug because it's been 48 hours during which the criteria supposedly were met. 6 0-votes, 20-23 1+ votes during the whole period. The criteria only last so long, so it may go out of scope soon. If it only checks every 3 days, I'm not sure if that's intentional or a bug.

Comment: @grace: thanks, didn't know about that search. haven't done much with the custom searches yet. :-)

Comment: Happy to help ♪

Comment: I [just proposed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97948) add this information to the faq.

Comment: Here is a working updated Query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 73, accepted):

- Only accepted answers older than 10 days are considered (otherwise tons of new users would get this)
- As long as they are not self accept
- And they are not wiki
- And they are not deleted

Comment: so is it retroactive, as in "if it was true 7 days ago"? this is one of those odd badges that if i don't manage to achieve it now, it's not likely to ever happen, no matter how many obscure things i help people with. :-)

Comment: not retroactive ... its meant as a consolation badge for people who participate in obscure tags that don't get any upvotes

Comment: @waffles - huh, did they change the name of this to "tenacious"? i just got it, by the way. :-)

Comment: @eruciform, yep, same badge, new name, see [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/improvements-to-badge-system/)

Comment: Turns out its 10 days: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71273/confused-by-unsung-hero-calculation/71274#71274

Comment: @yahelc thanks and oops ... corrected that

Comment: @waffles- to be clear, self accepted answers that would be beneficial in earning the badge are not considered nor are they, beneficial or not, considered into the total number of accepted answers.

Comment: I was also kinda stumped by this, since I got the 'Tenacious' badge at a weird moment, and now also I meet the 'Unsung Hero' requirements but didn't get it yet. I think the badge descriptions need to be clarified some, and a link to this answer added.