# Unsung Hero badge - more than 3 days delay?

Tags: bug, badges, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long do Tireless and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tireless-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

I've been puzzled by this one by now. Got my 11-th zero-score accepted answer more than 3 days ago. Have a total of 32 accepted answers (meaning the percentage is at 11/32 ~= 34% > 25%).

Is there something wrong with the calculations or my understanding of the requirements, or does it simply take more time to award the badge?

My profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/240424/yakimych

Comment: One week it is then. Couldn't find this info myself :( Thanks!

Comment: Turns out it's actually 10 days. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71273/confused-by-unsung-hero-calculation/71274#71274