# Confused by Unsung Hero calculation

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I feel really stupid asking about this (because its clearly so trivial), but its been bugging me.

Counting my own '[Accepted Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:172322%20isaccepted:1&tab=votes)', I count 12 Accepted Answers with a score of 0. None of them are community wiki, none of them are self-answered.

So, in theory, with 12 Zero Vote accepted answers out of <strike>31</strike> 42 Accepted answers (<strike>38%</strike> 28%), I should have the Unsung Hero badge. I've read that it takes a week for it to count, but only 1 of my questions is from the past week (which would make it 26%).

Am I missing something?

Comment: You actually have 43 accepted answers. You have to count the 0 vote answers as well. Although you would still be over the 25% mark.

Comment: That's a good question. You actually have 43 accepted answers so your percentage is 27%, but it looks like you should have been at 26% even before your last 0-point accepted answer four hours ago. I'd suggest [How Unsung Am I?](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=172322), but we're right at the start of the month so the data is pretty old.

Comment: Brandon, Michael Myers, you're right. Edited to reflect the fix. But still would mean 26-28%. 'How Unsung Am I' is way off, as the data is a month old, so only 'sees' 7 of my unsung questions.  http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/345/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=172322

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[The threshold is 10 days, not 7 days](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/283872#283872), according to [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha), who corrected the original input [on the badge repository](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) after looking at the actual code.

You have 2 zero-score accepted answers within 10 days: the one within a week and [this one here from the 22nd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245132/google-analytics-api-filter-by-uri/4248251#4248251). That makes only 10 zero vote accepted answers, which out of either 42 or 43 yields less than 25%. As long as you don't get votes or skew your ratio in any other fashion, you should have the badge in a day or two.

Comment: Interesting. That seems pretty authoritative. That means that this accepted answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tireless-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded/57834#57834 , amongst others, is incorrect.

Comment: @yahelc Aye, that is indeed incorrect (and was where I actually found the original 7 days marker that I posted on the badge repository).

Comment: Excluding the past 10 days, I'm actually at 10/37, which is 27%, but not **more** than 10. So, I'll get my 11th qualifying answer either tomorrow or the day after.

Comment: @yahelc Amusing. So, the 10 day issue is the root of your problem, but the reason is because of the absolute number of answers rather than the ratio. Also, don't feel stupid about asking questions. Sometimes things don't make sense.