# Unsung Hero Badge 7,8 or 10 days after the last zero scored accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer, zero-score-badges

I was expecting to receive my stackoverflow unsung hero badge in 2 days time (10 days after the 10th zero scored accepted answer)

But surprise, I received it today. 8 days after the last zero scored accepted answer.

8 days doesn't make sense, it's maybe 7 days from the time the data are processed in SO.

Here's my question numbers and date of acceptance to prove it.

```
Question | Accepted
---------+------------
10821974 | 31/05/2012
10968127 | 11/06/2012
10897574 | 12/06/2012
10969547 | 13/06/2012
10998253 | 15/06/2012
11052130 | 20/06/2012
11049830 | 16/06/2012
11105265 | 20/06/2012
11122643 | 20/06/2012
11153866 | 25/06/2012
```

I also have 1 self accepted from the 31/05/2012 (10802376) and (11052130) has been accepted the 16/06/2012, unaccepted and reaccepted the 20/06/2012. But they don't seems to count anyway.

It cannot be 10 days as suggest https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71274/187892

Do you consider it took 7 or 8 days? Or am I missing something?

---

**EDIT:**

@DanielFischer seems to be right, my 10th zero scored accepted answer is from 22/06/2012 17:24.

On this basis, I received the Unsung Hero badge after **10 days** and few hours after my 10th zero scored accepted answer was **posted**.

```
Question | Accepted   | Answered
---------+------------+-----------------
10821974 | 31/05/2012 | 30/05/2012 18:25
10968127 | 11/06/2012 | 06/06/2012 19:14
10897574 | 12/06/2012 | 10/06/2012 13:32
10969547 | 13/06/2012 | 11/06/2012 21:42
10998253 | 15/06/2012 | 14/06/2012 22:00
11052130 | 20/06/2012 | 15/06/2012 14:31
11049830 | 16/06/2012 | 15/06/2012 14:43
11105265 | 20/06/2012 | 19/06/2012 16:45
11122643 | 20/06/2012 | 20/06/2012 15:51
11153866 | 25/06/2012 | 22/06/2012 17:24
```

Comment: Now I'm curious, how did I become a Richard? Bobby, I'd understand (since you never saw me playing chess).

Comment: @DanielFischer May have heard richard on the TV when typing, really sorry for that and thanks for the answer.

Comment: No need to be sorry, I wasn't offended. I was just curious, since Richard wasn't obvious, nothing similar, like David would have been.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wording is

> Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered

I read that as "the answer must be at least ten days old", the accept date doesn't count for that. So if you are lucky and the job runs soon after you fulfilled the requirements, you would get the badge even on the same day as the accept.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my post to prove it.