# Unsung Hero gold badge

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer

I have seen the Unsung Hero gold badge which is awarded on 10 accepted answers with total scores of zero.

My 10 answers have been accepted with score of 0. I have answered a total of 107 questions on which 13 are answers with 0 score. Out of these 13, 3 are answers to my own questions after research, but there are 10 questions which are accepted by other users.

I have still not been awarded the Unsung Hero gold badge. What is the reason?

Comment: FYI, you only have **9** qualifying zero-score accepts, because one of the zero-scoring accepts is community wiki and is therefore ignored, thus you don't meet the requirements at the moment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The 25% is out of total accepted answers, not all answers, so you look to be well over that threshold anyway.

Get 1 more 0 score accepted answer, then wait about a week and you should get it.

Comment: Is that true also for the Tenacious badge?

Answer (score 33):

You do have [10 accepted non-wiki answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a526367%20isaccepted%3a1%20wiki%3a0) with 0 upvoted.

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340207/how-can-i-moderate-comments-in-the-facebook-fbcomments-social-plugin/4342755#4342755),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115352/customizing-title-and-description-using-facebook-share-in-an-iframe/4646718#4646718),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874346/html-form-send-blank/4874456#4874456),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918637/fetching-google-images-through-html-dom-parser/4932902#4932902),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988378/how-to-find-out-maximum-number-of-likes-and-comments-in-facebook-using-graph-api/4988989#4988989),[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058856/i-got-empty-response-from-create-album-in-facebook-graph-api/5059121#5059121),[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068568/replace-fanbox-with-like-box/5138634#5138634),[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256121/email-notification-in-web-app-use-cron-or-bcc/5256159#5256159),[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258182/enable-disable-of-textbox-on-option-selected-from-drop-down-menu/5258409#5258409),[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271917/facebook-fbrequest-form-not-working/5272210#5272210)

But [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918637/fetching-google-images-through-html-dom-parser/4932902#4932902) of them is your own accepted answer, that [does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tireless-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded).

Comment: As always good catch! How did you find this? Any tips? :-)

Comment: @Shadow, I just searched "[user:526367 isaccepted:1 wiki:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a526367%20isaccepted%3a1%20wiki%3a0)" on search box and clicked all the links for this answer. (for general tips, I use to search at search box, google, browse through google's cache of old page, edit history, suggest history at 10k tools, user activities/responses/reputation list at profile, ....)

Comment: @YOU does your own accepted answer count toward the 75% of total answers keeping you from getting the badge?

Answer (score 3):

Unsung Hero: Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total

10 is not more than 10, and is less than the 25% fo 107

Comment: the 25% is of accepted answers, not of answers.