# Unsung Hero gold badge requirement

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Unsung Hero” requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement)

The rule for Unsung Hero is

> Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

I want to know what if a **person accepted his/her own answer of zero score**? Is this answer  going to be used in the calculation for the badge?

Comment: Own accepted answer is not count.For details see a link


http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86355/unsung-hero-gold-badge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, self accepted answer is not counted. Also deleted and wiki answers are not counted for Unsung Hero Badge Requirement.

> #### Unsung Hero
>
> - gold; awarded once; same family as Tenacious (silver)
> - Have more than ten accepted answers with a score of zero, and have those zero-score accepted answers account for at least 25% of all your
>     accepted answers
>
>   - Only accepted answers at least ten days old are considered
>   - Community Wiki answers, deleted answers, and self-accepted answers are not included in any calculations
> - Source: [How long do Tireless and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded),
>     a SO team member who checked the source code [in
>     chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/284001#284001)

Original [Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/173001).