# Why am I not getting the Unsung Hero Badge?

Tags: discussion, badge-request, zero-score-badges

So, I was waiting desperately that I would get one more answer accepted with and I would get this Badge, but it happened differently.

I was stuck on perfect count of 40 accepted answers and 10 accepted answers with score 0, which wouldn't get me the badge as the badge says `Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.`

But then, one of my accepted answers which had a score of -1 got an upvote and so now, I had 40 accepted answers with 11 accepted answers of score 0!

Now, as per the rules, I would get it right?

Btw, I checked the count with the help of this query 'user:593336 isaccepted:1'

**UPDATE**

I read somewhere that it takes 8-10 days for this badge to approve? Is it so? Mine is just a day old.

Comment: That would be my fault, I wrote a song about you once and unfortunately that means you are ineligible for the badge. ;P

Comment: Dammit! Please unsong/dissong your song! I want that badge :p

Comment: I think _score=0_ **!=** _(upvote+downvote i.e 10-2 =8)_ I'm not sure about it. I may be wrong

Comment: posting on meta is a good way to ruin your prospects for the badge... let's see which of those answers deserve some upvotes...

Comment: Haha.. Sure. Upvoting all of them would also be a better option! :)

Comment: Here is a working query https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 11 accepted answers with 0 vote. Out of which one was by [accepted by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455082/play-silent-videos-alongwith-the-music-app-playing-songs). ( 11- 1 =10)

And one was [accepted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12826216/how-do-i-move-all-the-data-from-nsmutablearray-to-nsarray-with-a-key),

Community assumes your question is active for 10 days. So you can get up-votes until 10 days. And if your question is accepted with zero votes and [criteria for unsung hero](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/178505) is satisfied. You will definitely get the Unsung Hero badge.

See also posts :

1. ["Unsung Hero" requirement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement)
2. [Unsung Hero gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86355/unsung-hero-gold-badge)
3. [When exactly does the Unsung Hero badge get awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123519/when-exactly-does-the-unsung-hero-badge-get-awarded)