# Total accepted answers for Unsung Hero

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer, zero-score-badges

I now have 11 accepted zero-score answers, the most recent one I posted on Feb 3 at 1:30.

I also have 33 accepted non-zero-score answers (including one self-accepted), of which 6 were posted after the most recent zero-score answer. I think this means I will gain the 'Unsung Hero' badge if there are no changes, on 13/02/2013.

My question is whether these 6 accepted answers are included in the total accepted answer count?

In other words, if I get more non-zero score accepted answers in the coming days, do I still earn the Unsung Hero badge on 13/02/2013?

Comment: I would assume self-accepted don't really count toward the badge.

Comment: @J.Steen I know that, but this is not the point to my question. My point is the accepted answer that answered after the lastest zero score accepted answer.

Comment: This is also discussed here: [Why am I not getting the Unsung Hero Badge?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150170/190341) and it has a nice comment from [ronalchn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193598/ronalchn): *"posting on meta is a good way to ruin your prospects for the badge... let's see which of those answers deserve some upvotes..."* :)

Comment: yes [the self-accepted answers don't count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/182516).

Comment: @insertusernamehere yes, I was stupid.

Comment: I'm also insanely curious as to why you would *desire* this badge? Don't you want your answers to be perceived as helpful by the community?

Comment: @J.Steen I'm not desiring this badge on purpose, I seen it recently, and search for some detail about it, just so.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then. Your question made it seem like you were desiring it, and trying to set yourself up to get it deliberately. =)

Comment: @J.Steen I can't control the zero-score accepted answer, and I will lose the badge because of this question. BTW, I am still glad of more upvote.

Comment: Naturally. Aren't we all. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When your zero-score accepted answers are all at least 10 days old and still at 0 votes, *then* the total count of accepted answers is taken into account.

[Self-accepted answers do not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement) in this equation. Note that [only accepted answers at least 10 days old](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123519/when-exactly-does-the-unsung-hero-badge-get-awarded) are considered *at all* for the equation.

This means the 6 more recent answers are not taken into consideration; they are not going to be 10 days old by the time your most recent 0-score accepted answer 'matures'.

On the 13th, *if your answer still has a score of 0*, you'll have 11 accepted 0-score answers, and provided that the total accepted answers that are at least 10 days old at that point is 44 or less you get the badge. By my count that would be 39 accepted answers old enough to qualify.

So, to put it differently, the query for the badge looks up all accepted answers that are 10 days old, and are not self-accepted, deleted or community wiki, then checks that at least 10 of those are at 0 points and if that makes for more than 25% of the qualifying accepted answers.

But I see that 2 of your recent 0-score answers have been upvoted now. Tough luck, you'll have to answer more questions now to redress the balance if you really want that badge. If the answers are *downvoted* again to 0, then you'd still get the badge, but for your sake I hope that doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank you for your post, I'm clear now. But I will delete this question a few later, and do best to get this badge :)

Comment: @pktangyue: Sorry, you cannot delete this question now that you have two answers on it.

Comment: Eh..you're right, and I have no choice.

Comment: @pktangyue - Even if you "succeed" in getting more 0-score answers added, some of your other answers might get accepted as well, putting it below 25% again. Some of us are proud *not* to have that badge. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, and I will let nature take its course
.