# Is the Unsung Hero badge a bad thing?

Tags: discussion, badges, accepted-answer, zero-score-badges

Everyone seems excited to get the Unsung Hero badge. Is this really a good thing? It seems in this case it is encouraging users to do abnormal thigns they wouldn't do otherwise, and try to get zero-score accepted answers. For instance, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166608/total-accepted-answers-for-unsung-hero) question on meta.

Comment: To me, it's not really good or bad, but more of a consolation prize.  "Thanks for sticking with us and providing valuable answers even though no one is upvoting you!"  I have a theory that if all you ever do is answer Crystal Reports answers, there's a good chance you'll get it :P

Comment: Let the badge-hunters badge-hunt. It'll help the lesser-viewed questions get answered too.

Comment: @Doorknob Yes, it seems fine unless you have people being undesirable for a badge, deleting answers and such.

Comment: @MarJamRob: Deleting answers isn't really a problem. It only even looks at answers that are accepted, and you can't delete your answer while it's accepted.

Comment: Related: [Was the Unsung Hero a bad idea to implement?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56897/was-the-unsung-hero-a-bad-idea-to-implement)