# Does answering your own question earn credit toward the "Tenacious" badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

If I answer my own questions, will this count toward the [Tenacious badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/69/tenacious)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**  Answering your own questions do not count.

I searched MSO and found a reasonable [explanation here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded/57834#57834).