# Why is Unsung Hero not awarded?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges, zero-score-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How long does it take for badges to be awarded? How are they generated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/how-long-does-it-take-for-badges-to-be-awarded-how-are-they-generated)
>   [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

I know this question has been posted many a times, but unfortunately none helped!

I was randomly going through my answers in SO, I observed that I am eligible for the **Unsung Hero** badge, but its not in my profile yet :-/

Some stats:

- **10** out of **24** are 0 rated
- I never answered my own question
- All the questions that I answered (which were 0 voted) are active for more than 12 days

Am I missing some requirement yet?

Comment: Did you *just* become eligible?  It does take a certain amount of time for badges to be awarded.  IIRC some badges are awarded in the overnight jobs.

Comment: I am not sure when did I eligible, but according to stats I was eligible 2 ago.

Comment: Are those **accepted** answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait on it.

Your last 2 0-score answers just became 0-score 4 hours ago due to a couple of downvotes.

When I became eligible for UnsungHero myself, it took some days before I got it

Comment: But why the query (mentioned by Crazy Buddy) is giving me the wrong result?

Comment: I don't know exactly.  My guess would be that data.stackexchange has a seperate database that's only migrated at the end of the day, but that's just a guess

Comment: ohk. I more thing how did you traced this thing, just curious to know.

Comment: @Shadowfax I looked at your profile http://stackoverflow.com/users/1343690/sahil?tab=reputation

Comment: @Shadowfax Just to clarify it takes at [least 10 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded). Also you can use ninja search options to make it easy to find [user:me isaccepted:1 score:0](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+isaccepted%3A1+score%3A0)

Answer (score 1):

As Sam says, it takes some time for badges. It is also limited by a situation (not just 5 selected 0-score answers, but also) 25 % of total 0-scored ones.

Looks like you *are* lucky (36%). You could find your results in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)...

Comment: The query is giving me the wrong result. Instead of 24 accepted answers(ten 0 voted), its showing 22 accepted answers(eight 0 voted). How come? And yes, I am not lucky if I have that much of 0-scored answers :(

Comment: The data-explorer is updated weekly @Shadowfax, you're expecting things to happen slightly too quickly...

Comment: @Shadowfax: As all say, PLEASE WAIT for a while. One more thing: Badges and rep. score, etc. are just to *encourage* users. They don't necessarily have to be considered as a big popularity like some "Gold medal or Nobel", like that :-)

Comment: I understand that Crazy, what made you feel that i was impatient? Its just that I was curious to know, i thought may be some bug .. :)