# Do users with low numbers of accepted answers meet criteria for "Tenacious"?

Tags: support, badges, accepted-answer, zero-score-badges

Would users with a low number of accepted answers meet the criteria for "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero"?

I currently have 6 accepted zero-score answers out of a total 8 accepted answers. Does this meet the criteria for "Tenacious"?

Similarly, will other newer users with low number of accepted answers (~10 but more than 5 are accepted) receive the badge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter what your accepted vs. total answers ratio is. Only accepted answers count, non-accepted answers have no bearing on this.

Note that:

> - Only accepted answers older than 10 days are considered (otherwise tons of new users would get this)
> - As long as they are not self accept
> - And they are not wiki
> - And they are not deleted

(Source: [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded))

However, the badge description tells you you need **more** than 5 accepted answers at score 0; you have *exactly* 5 qualifying answers. You do have a 6th 0-score accepted answer but it is not yet old enough; you'll have to wait another week before it would qualify, provided it stays at 0.

Comment: what are "self-accepts"? As far as i know they are other users who accepted my answers

Comment: @ylun: oops, it's late at night; none are self-accepts. I'll correct.

Comment: then what "...and 20% of total." this part means.?@MartijnPieters

Comment: @Saif: 20% of all your accepted answers older than 10 days which are not self accepted, wiki or deleted.

Comment: @Saif: you have a total of 6 accepted answers that meet those criteria. Only 1 of those 6 has a score of 0, so that's 16.67% of the total.

Comment: Thanks for explaining got it now. @MartijnPieters