# Yet another question about Tenacious badge

Tags: discussion, badges, zero-score-badges

I apologize for one more time when question about "Tenacious" badge is asked. I think it's because this badge is one of most complicated ones. I know about most of requirements for getting it (which are: 6 or more accepted answers have 0 score, 20% or more of all answers are accepted ones and have 0 score, 0 score accepted answers to my own questions don't count, 10 days should pass). In my case I have 6 such answers out of 30 (all my answers). Now I'll describe my problem. Yesterday was the 7-th day of 10 days while I fit the requirements. But by mistake I made 31-st answer and then removed it 5 minutes later without any up/down vote or comment. Now it's 20% again. But intrigue is were these 10 days cleared yesterday and should I wait 10 more days now?

Comment: by mistake you made an answer but removed it? You're deliberately not answering things in case they get upvotes and keep you from getting the badge?

Comment: @Kate you won't believe what people are doing for badges, but starting such discussion here won't do any good. (just a friendly tip :))

Comment: Nope, I'm answering because I want to help. But on the other hand why can't I get positive feedback by getting badge? Do you think it's not ethical? My mistake was that I forgot that I decided to wait 10 days. What's wrong with me?

Comment: The more I think about it the worse I feel. @KateGregory, let me do some psychological analysis. When I was answering I realized that I'm not satisfied by feedback. Do you think it's better to drop answering on StackOverflow than to find missing amount of motivation in getting badges (if I merited them)? And another question is don't you think that your judgment is too much of black and white?

Comment: I didn't make a judgment. I asked a question. Two questions, actually. I wanted to clarify what you wrote. I don't think there is something wrong with you, or that you should feel bad. But I am puzzled to see someone taking specific actions to try to earn these badges, which I always thought of as "consolation prizes" that you get when you just keep on answering answering answering, helping with no reward because you're in low volume tags or whatever. I didn't think of them as badges to be worked for. I'm curious, not judgmental.

Comment: In case it's not clear from the answer here, several of your conditions are wrong, referring to answers instead of *accepted* answers. *Only accepted answers on others' questions are considered in any way for Tenacious and Unsung Hero.*

Comment: @KateGregory, if you're really curious and not judging then it may be interested for you to take a look at structure of my motivation for spending time in participation in StackOverflow. I made a list of motivating factors as accurate as I can: (1) Challenging questions (I love brainteasers) - 25%; (2) Altruistic help - 20%; (3) Professional self-satisfaction - 15%; (4) Self-learning in areas of interest - 15%; (5) Socialization in discussions around problems and solutions -10%; (6) Respect from community-10%; (7) Ideas for startup/open source - 3%; (8) Searching for fresh trending topics - 2%

Comment: And honestly I don't think there are many people being 100% pure altruists.

Comment: @NathanTuggy, yes, you're right, I described these requirements differently from what I knew at the time of asking. I corrected it. But I left second requirement wrong on purpose because I didn't understand it right at the time of asking.

Comment: @KateGregory, and regarding to your questions directly. The answer that I made by mistake and removed 5 minutes later was the answer to my own question. So there is nothing unethical in keeping this question unanswered few more days because author is myself and now I know the answer without posting it. It's only few days of waiting before knowledge I learnt will be shared with others.

Comment: I just received the infamous Tenacious badge. I suppose I will covet that one.  I have been always amazed at how many of my (hard earned and time consumed) answers are never voted up even once while for other's very superficially answered questions have received a TON of votes by the "populace". Having common motivations (of those using SE) explained has helped explain this.  Some frequently see it as a social game while others are motivated by answering where they can - contributing to good answers. All SE sites are different with some worse than others with "points consumed" participants.

Comment: StackExchange is truly an excellent resource for good answers to difficult honest questions in many fields.  That is why I started to use it and participate.  But, I wish the common "social, rewards based zeal" would extend to difficult questions that are quickly dismissed after just a few days - and then receive no further attention at the sites.  That is what an "expert" or even a truly "subject interested novice" in any field would do. Invest in or spread that question around (refer it to, or confer with) others who may be able to answer it - no rewards required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here is what's going on.

Right now, you have total of  15 answers that have been accepted by OP.

Out of these 15, total of 7 have score of 0.

However, [one of those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867212/get-mysqldump-error-message-from-java/32875907#32875907) is not yet 10 days old. (posted 8 days ago)

[Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32534070/really-long-strings-in-json-1-gig-with-jackson-token-stream/32575692#32575692) is self accepted.

This leaves only 5 answers that meet all the criteria [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834/152859), and the requirement is **more than 5**, which means 6 and above.

You should get the badge within 2-3 days, when [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867212/get-mysqldump-error-message-from-java/32875907#32875907) will reach 10 days, assuming its score will still be 0 of course.